# PSQLException: This ResultSet is closed.

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, resultset

Im having this problem that I cant do a executeQuery and then a executeUpdate in the same method it gives me "PSQLException: This ResultSet is closed."
I have tried to create another statement and other ResultSet but with no success. I you have any Idea how you help me, I would appreciate it. Thanks

```
Statement stmt = pc.getStatement();
try
{
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from artigos where 
        artigoc="+s);

    while (rs.next())
    {
        int stock = rs.getInt("stock");

        stmt.executeUpdate("update artigos set stock="+newStock+","
                + "vendidos="+newVendidos+" where artigoc="+s);
    }
    rs.close(); // muito importante depois da consulta!
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    System.err.println("Problems retrieving data from db...");
}
```

Comment: in exception related questions, it helps if you post the stacktrace

Comment: *FYI:* You should use [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) on both `Statement` and `ResultSet`.

Comment: @Andreas I already did it

Comment: @FilipeCarvalho If you already did, why is the code in the question not doing it? I think you're confusing a regular `try` statement with a [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) statement.

Comment: Also, don't use string concatenation to insert values into a SQL statement. Use a `PreparedStatement` with parameter markers (`?`).

Comment: you don't need a loop or two separate statements for that. You can do this with a single update which will be a lot more efficient to begin with

Answer (score 1):

The javadoc of [`Statement`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html) says:

> All execution methods in the `Statement` interface implicitly **close a current `ResultSet`** object of the statement if an open one exists.

Use a different `Statement` object to execute the update.